# OSM Nominatim: cant import data on new server

Tags: php, openstreetmap, centos7, nominatim

i'm trying to setup my own nominatim server in a CentOS 7 VirtualMachine. I'm using [this guide](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/appendix/Install-on-Centos-7/) which is followed [here for data import](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Import-and-Update/).

This line gives me trouble when trying to import data:

```
./utils/setup.php --osm-file <data file> --all --osm2pgsql-cache 1500 2>&1 | tee setup.log
```

When excecuting the above command, the output says "ERROR: Scripts must be run from build directory.".

Which one would be the build directory?

I tryed running from nominatim root directory, utils, and data, but no luck.

Help in this question is much appreciated.

Best regards,
    Federico.

Comment: Offtopic, since this question is not related to programmng. Ask your question at http://help.openstreetmap.org/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks scai for the tip.

Got an answer from [help.openstreetmap.org](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/62251/nominatim-setupphp-error-scripts-must-be-run-from-build-directory/62254).

The command was meant to be run from the "build" folder, that was it.

Best regards, Federico.